# Is Django's update_object generic view secure? Should I extend it or make my own for security?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-generic-views

I'm new to Django. Last night I worked hard on a view that would allow me to edit any of the entities in my current project; Chapters, Stories, and Worlds. In order to ensure that I know precisely which database object is being modified, I added a database entry to the tables 'edits' that stores the hash, the type of object being edited (eg. 'Chapter'), and the id of that object as found in the database. The hash is added to the form as a hidden input.

On the back-end, after the form has been submitted, I grab the hash and use it to find the related Edit item in the database. I then use this to find which object was initially being edited. This was done for two reasons:

1. I can know what object is truly being edited. If all form items have changed, there would be nothing to compare to (except URLs) to actually know which object is being edited.
2. Users should be unable to hack the front-end to do weird things like modify the wrong stories.

Today I discovered that Django has a generic view called `update_object`. This seems to handle a lot of things for me. But given that it doesn't automatically use the database to ensure that the correct object is being edited, or even determine *which* object is being edited, is this secure? surely there must be a simple way to hack it on the front end by modifying HTML elements.

Secondly, if this should be a concern, would you recommend that I keep my own edit view, or that I extend the update_object view, or some other solution?

Lastly, am I going about this the right way at all? Please correct me if I'm not thinking about solutions to this problem in the right way.

I don't feel that this is a question that requires code. It's more of a general question about the security of forms as they pertain to Django.

Thanks,

ParagonRG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem of knowing which object they're editing is typically solved either by inspecting the URL or by a hidden form element that just has the database ID.

Before accepting any changes from a user form, you should be verifying that the user has permission to do whatever it is they're asking to be doing, and that the edits make sense. You'd normally do this with form validators and/or explicit checks in the view. This is a somewhat safer way of dealing with this problem, because it guarantees people aren't making DB changes they're not allowed to be making, whereas in your `Edit` object approach it's conceivable they could get around that.

If you take this approach, I don't see any reason why it's a problem that the user could be editing hidden ID fields to pretend to be editing a different object. They're just using a silly roundabout way to edit things when they could have just gone to a different edit link.

(Also: if you're using Django 1.3+, it's better to use the new class-based [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) rather than the function-based `update_object`.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that those generic views are deprecated! I'll have to mess around with UpdateView. Also, interestingly enough, I don't see hidden form element that indicates which object is being edited. Check it out here (it's pretty short): http://dpaste.com/733945/ . It's a World object, and its ID is 1. There isn't much else to identify it with, and I see neither in that code. How could it be working without it?

Comment: @Paragon I suppose it's using the URL rather than a hidden ID, which is pretty much equivalent. As it happens, you can see the source of the views [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py); if you follow the trail of inheritance back, it ends up at [this method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L19) that finds objects based on the `pk` or `slug` or whatever argument in the URL pattern.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. This puts my mind on the right track.